# Django Tiny MCE and Static files

Tags: django, django-tinymce, django-static

I have django tinymce setup but I hav noticed an issue with the tool when not in debug mode. The advanced theme has some templates in it, these templates contain django template code. The problem is that these templates are being served out of the static folder, which will not let them render.

Does any one know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
CG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in django `runserver` command serves static files, but only when `DEBUG=True`. In production, you need to configure your webserver to serve static files.

The [static files documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: HI Alasdair, I understand how to serve static files, the issue I am experiencing is that for some reason django-tinymce includes some templates which need to be rendered in the static file, so when I setup nginx to serve my static files it breaks the template. The templates need to live at a different path and be rendered with a view, however I am wondering if I am missing something as it doesn't seem it should be so tricky to setup.

Comment: Ah, I understand. If the templates have django template code in them, then they're not static files, and shouldn't really be in your static folder. I know that doesn't help you much -- I'm afraid I'm not familiar with django-tinymce.

Comment: Yup, that is exactly my issue. The plugin was just incorrectly structured... or I am not sure what I did wrong. Thanks for offering your assistance any how :)

Comment: Hope you managed to fix your problem. You don't have to mark my answer as accepted if it didn't help. If you fixed it some other way, it would be better to add it as an answer, and accept that.